# How to enable default link button after preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I want to scroll top when user press Login button. I am using Link button as Login. Now here is my logic to scroll to top.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="cmdLogin" resourcekey="cmdLogin" cssclass="dnnPrimaryAction" text="Login" runat="server" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {

        var actionLinks = $("a[id$=cmdLogin]");
        actionLinks.click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            //    e.stopPropagation();
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 'fast');


        });

    });
</script>
```

The scrolling working fine with this code but the problem is when I click on login button it got disable. I can click it again but it prevent default css code and button seems like disable. It is actually not showing the error message because of preventDefault(). 
Please help me how can I enable default after using `event.preventDefault();`

Thanks.

Comment: can u try actionLinks.unbind('click')?

Comment: Ya I tired it but it didn't work..

Comment: can u share a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

replace `.click(` with `.one( "click",`

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var actionLinks = $("a[id$=cmdLogin]");
    actionLinks.one( "click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //    e.stopPropagation();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'fast');


    });

});
```

- The first time the button is pressed the event handler will run
- The second time the button is pressed, the default handler will run